# How to have Django `manage.py test` recognize pytest test method that has no unittest base class?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pytest

I'm running parallel unittesting using Django 's `manage.py test` command.

The issue is that this command only recognized the `unittest-way` test method - for those that has the pytest-way eg no test class and have fixture param, `manage.py test` will skip them.

So my question is how to get `manage.py test` collect the pytest-way test methods?

p.s.

The reason I go for Django unittest `manage.py test` is because of its `--parallel` feature ie it can handle beautifully test database creation for each parallel thread the test running in.

Comment: If you're writing pytest-style tests, then you need to switch to using `pytest` instead of `manage.py test` as the runner. You might find the [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin useful.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for pointing out - I added the reason why I need `Django unittest` to take care of in-parallel test database.

Comment: See [here](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#running-tests-in-parallel-with-pytest-xdist) for running the tests in parallel with pytest-django.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair to point out that pytest-django capable of handling parallel test databases as well - I'll try pytest-django and back to us later.

Comment: @Alasdair it's working using pytest-django to run test in parallel. Please add your answer to get accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working. You can add your own answer to say how you solved the problem.